# Javascript Question Regarding objects

Tags: javascript

I am hoping someone can explain how and why the answer to this question is... "Malibu".

Meet Sherlock Holmes, a world-renowned detective from London:

```
let sherlock = {
  surname: 'Holmes',
  address: { city: 'London' }
};
```

His friend, John Watson, recently moved in:

```
let john = {
  surname: 'Watson',
  address: sherlock.address
};
```

Sherlock is a brilliant detective, but a difficult flatmate. One day, John decides he’s had enough—he changes his surname and moves to Malibu:

```
john.surname = 'Lennon';
john.address.city = 'Malibu';
```

What is the answer to.... ***console.log(sherlock.address.city); // ?***

The answer is ***Malibu*** but can anyone explain why and how it is this?

Comment: It's just because Sherlock decided to follow Watson but didn't tell you. He probably travelled under a false identity too, what a sneaky dude he is

Answer (score 3):

Notice how `sherlock.address` is an object. The object `{ city: 'London' }`.

The code basically assigns the exact same object to `john`. So, `sherlock` and `john` live in the same house, that's fine. But then when `john` moves, it assigns `Malibu` to the city of his `address`, which is the exact same `address` object that `sherlock` is using, hence `sherlock` sees the change.

To fix this, instead of assigning the exact same address object, we need to make a copy.

There are many ways in Javascript to copy an object, but let's use this simple one (the object destructuring/spread operator syntax `{...ojb}`):

```js
let john = {
  surname: 'Watson',
  address: {...sherlock.address}
};
```

This way, instead of using the object `sherlock.address` as is, we copied it. After this, when `john` changes his city, it will not reflect to `sherlock`.

Another way is to declare an `address` object for `john` and copy the city, like this:

```js
let john = {
  surname: 'Watson',
  address: {city: sherlock.address.city}
};
```

---

Spread operator vs rest operator, `...`, similar syntax, different purpose:

The Spread operator is used to make a copy of an object, or merge multiple objects together (notice how it is used in the object you want to copy:

```js
const person = {name: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 59, email: "johndoe@gmail.com"};

const personCopy = {...person};

console.log(personCopy); // {name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 59, email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'}

// Merging objects:

const moreProperties = {city: "New York", isActive: true};

const merged = {...person, ...moreProperties};

console.log(merged); // {name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 59, email: 'johndoe@gmail.com', city: 'New York', isActive: true}
```

The rest operator is used to assign all the properties or the rest of the properties of an object to a variable (notice how it goes in the new variable to you to assign the rest of the properties to):

```js
const person = {name: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 59, email: "johndoe@gmail.com"};

// Here I'm only extracting the `name` and `lastName` properties of the object into their corresponding variables. Then, I use the rest operator `...` to assign the rest of the properties of `person` that I haven't extracted (copied) into the `restOfTheProperties` (could be named anything) variable, which is essencially a copy of all the remaining properties of the object.
const { name, lastName, ...restOfTheProperties} = person;

console.log(name); // "John"

console.log(lastName); // "Doe"

console.log(restOfTheProperties); // {age: 59, email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'}
```

It can also be used in function args, like this:

```js
function etc(...args) {
    console.log(args);
}

etc(1,2,3); // [1,2,3]
```

Could be used for arrays too.

More info here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-rest-vs-spread-operators/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I see what you mean,,.. they are both pointing to the same object (address) so when one is changed it reassigns both. Still a bit fuzzy but i think i see it. As far as the fix for it... can i ask you one question? is that "destructuring" method you are using the same as a "rest parameter" or a is that something different?

Comment: Similar syntax, different usage and purpose. See my update to answer. I put a couple of examples. This `...` operator is also used as a `varargs` operator in functions so you can send multiple arguments to a function and they are going to be treated as an array of those arguments. Like `function etc(...args)`, and would be called like `etc(1,2,3)`; and `args` then would be `[1,2,3]`.